# Android array error

Tags: android

```
This is my code:

public ArrayList generare_diferente(){
            int rezultat;
            ArrayList<String> termeni= new ArrayList<String>();
            int termA=parseInt(String.valueOf(randomBetween(1, 20)));
            int termB=parseInt(String.valueOf(randomBetween(1, 20)));
            if(termA<termB){
                int aux; aux=termA; termA=termB; termB=aux;
                rezultat=termA-termB;
                String diff = termA + "-" + termB;
                termeni.add(String.valueOf(rezultat));
                termeni.add(diff);

                Log.v("termeeeeni", String.valueOf(termeni));
            }
             return termeni;
        }
        public void generare_3_diferente() {
            ArrayList<String> scaderea1 = new ArrayList<String>();
            ArrayList<String> scaderea2 = new ArrayList<String>();
            ArrayList<String> scaderea3 = new ArrayList<String>();
            int raspuns_corect;
             int[] raspunsuri = new int[]{0, 0, 0, 0};
            int i = 0;
            do {
                scaderea1 = generare_diferente();
                scaderea2 = generare_diferente();
                scaderea3 = generare_diferente();
                Button scadere1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.scadere1);
                Button scadere2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.scadere2);
                Button scadere3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.scadere3);
                scadere1.setText((CharSequence) scaderea1.get(1));
                scadere2.setText((CharSequence) scaderea2.get(1));
                scadere3.setText((CharSequence) scaderea3.get(1));
            }
                while (scaderea1.get(0) == scaderea2.get(0) || scaderea2.get(0) == scaderea3.get(0) || scaderea3.get(0) == scaderea1.get(0));
            raspunsuri[1]= Integer.parseInt(scaderea1.get(0));
            raspunsuri[2]= Integer.parseInt(scaderea2.get(0));
            raspunsuri[3]= Integer.parseInt(scaderea3.get(0));
            pozitia_corecta = parseInt(String.valueOf(randomBetween(1, 3)));
            raspuns_corect = raspunsuri[pozitia_corecta];
            TextView rezultat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Rezultat);
            rezultat.setText(raspuns_corect);

        }
```

I'm getting this error:

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity : java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0

```
 Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0

        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
        at com.example.pinguin.MyActivity.generare_3_diferente(MyActivity.java:93)
        at .onCreate(MyActivity.java:24)
```

I don't understand why, the array should not have the size 0.
thank you!

Comment: `scadere1.setText((CharSequence) scaderea1.get(1));` Before access to element in index, you should check if scadere1 array is not empty.

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0` means your array doesn't have any elements and you're trying to access the element at `0`th index.

Comment: I think problem in your termA and termB generation.both is zero then if statement are not true so your array does not have any data

Comment: why are termA and termB 0?

Comment: if I print the array with Log.v, it is not null...

Comment: because you print arrayList Object not it's values

Comment: @ElenaE of course it shouldn't be null ,it should be empty so your log doesn't show null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code seems wrong. because in `generare_diferente()` if `termA<termB` or equal  you return empty array and then in `generare_3_diferente()` you try to read data from empty list.

first you should handle this issue.then I think your random number are not generate so termA and termB both is zero or anything and if statement are not true.
change code like this

```
public ArrayList generare_diferente(){
        int rezultat;
        ArrayList<String> termeni= new ArrayList<String>();
        int termA=random.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min ;
        int termB=random.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min ;
        if(termA<termB){
            int aux; aux=termA; termA=termB; termB=aux;
            rezultat=termA-termB;
            String diff = termA + "-" + termB;
            termeni.add(String.valueOf(rezultat));
            termeni.add(diff);

            Log.v("termeeeeni", String.valueOf(termeni));
        }
         return termeni.clone();
    }  

public void generare_3_diferente() {
        ArrayList<String> scaderea1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> scaderea2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> scaderea3 = new ArrayList<String>();
        int raspuns_corect;
         int[] raspunsuri = new int[]{0, 0, 0, 0};
        int i = 0;
        do {
            scaderea1 = generare_diferente();
            scaderea2 = generare_diferente();
            scaderea3 = generare_diferente();
            Button scadere1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.scadere1);
            Button scadere2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.scadere2);
            Button scadere3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.scadere3);
            if(scaderea1.size()>0 && scaderea2.size()>0 && scaderea3.size()>0){
            scadere1.setText((CharSequence) scaderea1.get(1));
            scadere2.setText((CharSequence) scaderea2.get(1));
            scadere3.setText((CharSequence) scaderea3.get(1));
            }else{
                scadere1.setText("something");
            scadere2.setText("something");
            scadere3.setText("something");
            break;
            }
        }
            while (scaderea1.get(0) == scaderea2.get(0) || scaderea2.get(0) ==   scaderea3.get(0) || scaderea3.get(0) == scaderea1.get(0));
        if(scaderea1.size()>0 && scaderea2.size()>0 && scaderea3.size()>0){
        raspunsuri[1]= Integer.parseInt(scaderea1.get(0));
        raspunsuri[2]= Integer.parseInt(scaderea2.get(0));
        raspunsuri[3]= Integer.parseInt(scaderea3.get(0));
        }else{
        raspunsuri[1]= Integer.parseInt("0");
        raspunsuri[2]= Integer.parseInt("0");
        raspunsuri[3]= Integer.parseInt("0");
        }
        pozitia_corecta = parseInt(String.valueOf(randomBetween(1, 3)));
        raspuns_corect = raspunsuri[pozitia_corecta];
        TextView rezultat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Rezultat);
        rezultat.setText(raspuns_corect);

    }
```